What is the correct way to refer to Ferdinand de Saussure: “Saussure” or “de Saussure”?
Are there established grammatical conventions or stylistic norms in academic writing regarding the use of particles in names, such as "de," "von," "di," etc.?

This question is similar to: How should 'van'-names be ordered in a bibliography?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In his Wikipedia article, he is referred to as Saussure unless his full name is given. I'd guess that is sufficiently canonical for use.
If you look at how some of his works are listed, you will find that he is named as Saussure, Ferdinand de. For example: https://archive.org/details/memoiresurlesyst00saus.
This doesn't seem to be a case of the older usage of "de" meaning a place of origin, as he was born in Geneva.
And, as you suggest such things are often included with the "last" name. I'm no linguist, but each case may be distinct.
Contrast this with Vincent de Paul where de does correspond to a "place", in this case a nearby stream.
There is a genus of plants called Saussurea, but Saussure doesn't seem to be associated with that. His father was an entomologist.

And just to back up Wikipedia with an authoritative published source: Saussure is referred to as ‘Saussure’, and listed under S, in Frawley’s International Encyclopedia of Linguistics (Oxford University Press, paywalled), and just about any other text in linguistics you care to check.

For famous people there is usually a common way by which they are known in English, but this varies by person.
Van Gogh is known as Van Gogh in English. On the other hand, Beethoven was Ludwig van Beethoven, but we don't call him van Beethoven. Similarly Saussure is best known as Saussure.
EDITED TO ADD: The APA page listed by Peter Jansson is not bad. It implies that it is only German and Portuguese where we omit van etc. Saussure is a good counterexample to this (he was born in Geneva, Switzerland and his name was French):

Ludwig van Beethoven is usually referred to in English as Beethoven and so would be credited as Beethoven, L. van, in the reference list entry and as Beethoven in the text. If you are writing in English, include the particle as part of the surname unless you know that the name is one of the famous German or Portuguese exceptions like Beethoven.


Is the informal rule you suggest valid for academic writing, which is what the OP asks about?

I certainly think so. Why would it not be? A style guide might say something different of course.

@Jagerber48 It's fine to use non-stilted language in academic writing.

@Jagerber48: One should follow whatever name is generally standard in existing academic writing in the field one’s writing in.  Sometimes this differs from the name most widely used by the public, or differs between academic fields (e.g. Chinggis/Genghis Khan) — but on this particular issue of including a de, van, etc, I don’t know any cases where popular and academic use differ.  And, in particular, Saussure is always Saussure.

Goethe isn't called von Goethe, but just Goethe.

I had to go look it up, but TIL that it's Ludwig van Beethoven and not Ludwig von Beethoven...

It is definitely a French custom to omit de when referring to people by their last name, especially when it's a title, e.g. Alexis de Tocqueville is Tocqueville, Armand Jean du Plessis de Richelieu is Richelieu.

The surname is 'de Saussure' and thus it should be listed as such. There are several sources detailing the use of  'de', 'von', 'van' etc. See for example the American Psychological Association. See also this post on Academia for more discussion.
One way to look at this is that the 'de' and its equivalent formulations are not part of the first name and so it should be part of the surname. In the end the reference style used by any specific journal may dictate otherwise but if you use a reference manager and add data properly and then use the reference style required, the reference should be reproduced properly.

Note that the academia post you link indicates that for van, at least, the usage isn't consistent, differing by country, at least. Why are you so definite. Lots of things aren't part of either the given or surname.

Historians don't always use the preamble to surnames. It's not standardized.

Saussure is pretty much never called ‘de Saussure’; listing him as such in bibliographies would be as unexpected as listing Beethoven under van (example courtesy of toby544’s answer) or, conversely, listing Leonardo da Vinci under V.

and than there are cultures where the surname appears first and the given name last and there are cultures where people don't have surnames... Names are just not as standardized as we like to think.

@MaartenBuis: Obligatory Falsehoods programmers believe about names

@JanusBahsJacquet Incidentally, listing Leonardo da Vinci under D would also be unexpected. Art historians working in English call him Leonardo, so it is L.

@toby544 Esteemed writer Dan Brown calls him "Da Vinci"

@AzorAhai-him- Very well put. Yes, renowned novelist Dan Brown does do that.

@toby544 While I’m sure that’s true of art historians, I’m less confident it holds for academia as a whole. Would engineers referring to him as a historical source and polyhistor call him Leonardo, for instance? I’m fairly sure I’ve seen him referred to in academic writing as Da Vinci, outside the writings of prominent penman Dan Brown (though I’m not sure it was in English).
